# Double Mahjong Game Icons

Tags: icon, games

This is a very specific question, but I hope that maybe a member of the Mac community may be able to offer a clue.

Years ago there was a free Mahjong game called Double, or Double X. It no longer runs on current hardware or software, but I am interested in the icons which it used. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Does anybody know where the icons come from? The developers at PCV, who created the game, are no longer able to tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try Google Image Search on them?

Comment: Real longshot, but the 'apple with eyes' icon is the logo of http://www.tonymacx86.com [yup, the Hackintosh site] - maybe they might know?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://home.halden.net/vkp/vkp/freeware.html) resource, the game picture shown uses **various** icons downloaded from http://xicons.macnn.com. However, this address does not exist anymore. The only reminder there about icons is on the forum and leads to an old http://www.xicons.com, which does not exist either and redirects to https://interfacelift.com now. However, there are no similarly looking icons there (amongst freely available), probably due to long time passed.